# What the difference between bsf filters? (ffmpeg)

Tags: video, encoding, filter, ffmpeg

What the difference between

```
bsf:v h264_toannexb
```

and

```
bsf:v dump_extra
```

And what filter should I use, when encode to HLS streaming (mpegts) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the format of the input. If your input is mp4  you should add both (`bsf:v dump_extra` is probably implied when you used HLS output). If yout input is already ts, you dont need `bsf:v h264_toannexb`

But really, to answer the question, you need to understand what extradata is, and what annebx b is: http://szatmary.org/blog/25